# USB-C - Power Delivery configuration options?

Tags: usb, power-management, battery, usb-c

Is there any way to see or configure Ubuntu's Power Delivery options?

One of my USB-C chargers doesn't provide sufficient power to my laptop.

- 45W charger - works on an Ubuntu laptop and ChromeBook
- 65W charger - works on an Ubuntu laptop and ChromeBook
- 85W charger - works on a ChromeBook, but only supplies about 20W to the Ubuntu laptop

I've tried different PD USB-C cables of different lengths. They all exhibit the same issue, but only on this specific laptop.

I can run:

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

To see how long the battery will take to charge, but I can't see how much power is being delivered.

Is there any way to see or configure what my laptop is negotiating?